# a quick way to maven install a lib folder

Tags: java, maven, build, build-automation

is there a quicker way to maven install say a complete lib folder to maven dependencies rather than the individual command for each jar:

```
mvn install:install-file -DgroupId=third-party -DartifactId=app-eventinfo -Dversion=1.0 -Dpackaging=jar -Dfile=EventInfoToOrder.jar
```

Is there a way I can say this is a folder of dependencies or a little work around in eclipse where I trick maven into using a user defined library as a dependency.

Yes I have a lot of folders that have been sitting on my buildpath which I must install to my local repo.

Cheers for reading :)

Comment: You have that many libraries not available from a repo?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is not about the folder contents, but specifying the correct values for `groupId`, `artifactId` and `version`.

If you are ok with random values for this, then you could write a dirty batch file/shell script to do this.

Otherwise, the time you spend trying to automate this (by having a mapping of `groupId`, `artifactId` and `version` for each jar in your folders), you can arguably do `mvn install:install-file` manually.

A better option would be to review your dependencies and see which are **not** available in maven repo and only install those.  The remaining will be downloaded by maven on its own.

Answer (score 1):

There is no standard way of doing this as it would go against Maven's philosophy of managed (versioned) dependencies.